# Consultar ultima fecha de acceso Login MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Saber el ultimo acceso de un Login a una base de datos en SQL Server;
Realice la siguiente consulta para obtener fechas sin embargo la funcion LOGINPROPERTY no contiene la ultima fecha de acceso de Login.

```
    SELECT 
     dbp.name AS [nombreUsuarioBD],
     slg.name AS [nombreLogin],
     LOGINPROPERTY ( slg.name , 'PasswordLastSetTime') AS 
     [ultimoCambioContraseña] ,
     LOGINPROPERTY ( slg.name , 'LockoutTime') AS [fechaDeBloqueo],
     LOGINPROPERTY ( slg.name , 'BadPasswordTime') AS 
     [ultimoIntentoContraseñaIncorrecta]
FROM sys.sql_logins slg
INNER JOIN 
sys.database_principals dbp
ON slg.sid = dbp.sid
WHERE slg.type IN ('U','S')
```

y consulte la tabla consultando la columna "accdate" sin embargo no trae informacion exacta.

```
 SELECT 
  name, 
  accdate
 FROM  
 sys.syslogins
```

Comment: ¿Versión del SQL Server? ¿Quieres obtener la última fecha que se autenticó?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Y Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo sería necesario consultar a la vista `SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS`.

```
SELECT MAX(LOGIN_TIME) [ULTIMA FECHA]
   ,LOGIN_NAME [CUENTA]
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS
GROUP BY LOGIN_NAME;
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [sys.dm_exec_sessions (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql)